# Parallel programming in games

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

in my game I have entities (about 2000-5000) that do very performance heavy calculations every frame (or every 2nd or 3rd).

I know that parallel programming will help in this scenario.
The question is how do I use multiple threads / cpu-cores in the best way possible.

I tried the static Parallel class in .NET, but the startup cost for every Parallel.For / Parallel.ForEach is simply to big.

Does it start a number of threads each time I call a function of the Parallel class ??
The game's target fps is 60 fps, so whatevery approach I use, it should never involve starting multiple threads every game-frame!

So my question is:
What other alternatives are there to parallel-process multiple entities?
Should I create the threads myself, and if so, what pitfalls are there?
Is the threadpool a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You need some computers or servers to test your parallel programmed game. Other wise on a single computer, since it will work on thread, it will cost more.

Additionally, since the game is calculated and drawn 60 times in a second, working on threads is not logical, your game is already running on threads.

Maybe you have to change or optimize your algorithm. Do not let everything is done by CPU, use GPU as much as possible.

Comment: Why is his game running on threads when he's not using any threads? He have one single game loop which is running on one thread and that's also the rendering thread.

Comment: @user743414 there are different approaches for update and render operations. you can run both tasks in parallel or first update can take place and render will follow it, etc. Game development requires threading so that it can use all CPU power. Not only the game loop also update may use threading.

Comment: Sure you can run both operations on different threads. The question is does synchronizing those two threads take more time than to just make it on one thread? Switching from one thread to onother is an expensive operation. I wrote that, and I also wrote what's the problem with threads and that he have to check if his game logic will break or not.

Comment: @user743414 I wrote down the best known ways, so you may run them in parallel. The performance depends on your core count and thread usage. Switching threads are not expensive as you mentioned, since they are running in same memory block. Well, you may need mutexes or semaphores, but this one also depends on your design. Think about processors designed for gaming tabletss, why do they have multiple cores if games would work only on one?

Answer (score 1):

By default the Parallel.For/Parallel.Foreach uses ThreadPool thread. Infact TPL api like Parallel class, Task instance etc uses ThreadPool thread.

The number of threads started by TPL will depend upon lots of factors like number of available ideal thread in threadpool etc. So assuming TPL will create lots of threads as soon as you will submit request will not be entirely correct.

Important point is that you can control, the number of threads used the TPL for executing the tasks via MaxDegreeOfParallelism flag. By setting this value to say number "X", you limit the number of concurrent items being processed to "X". Personally, I feel this is a very powerful feature of TPL library.

Also, if you do not want your task to block other requests in queue, then you can set the TaskCreationOptions to be of type "LongRunning", in that case, TPL will run the task on a dedicated thread.

In your case, you can try using Parallel.For/ForEach and set the MaxDegreeOfParalleleism value to some optimal value and see how that behaves.

Comment: Task does not use a thread http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple answer.

When every entity of your game can be calculated without knowing any other entity then you can simply move that calcultion to a given number of threads. A threadpool would be a good start.
You could set this up when your programm starts.
But even when you do so, you have to check if switching threads performs better than having one single thread. Context switch is here the keyword you can search for.

But what happens when entity A on thread A does a calculation with affects entity B on thread B and forces entity B to be destroyed which forces entity C on thread C to be destroyed also?
And now to make it harder :P entity C was calculated before entity B, before entity A...

What should happen? Is it ok that those entities will be cleaned up in 2 or 3 frames in the future?
Does it affect or break your game logic?

If so then things are getting complicated.